# Mysql. Change date format output on GROUP BY DAY query

Tags: mysql

I execute this query

```
SELECT * FROM graph WHERE ean IN ('00000000166330') group by DAY(created_at);
```

Getting those results:

```
# id,         ean,       avg_price,       created_at
'58', '00000000166330', '2799.0000', '2020-06-11 16:43:27'
```

I want to change the date format returned of the created_at field.
I would like to get only the date, not the hour, and with the format: Day, month, Year.

My guess is that DATE_FORMAT should be used, but how to use it, grouping also by day?

[Example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1ef8ce4b768409709b77d3169239b1d0)

Comment: You are using `group by` without doing any aggregation. Why? Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: add `DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d, %m, %Y) as formated_created_at` to your selects

Comment: Example added to main post

Comment: forpas If I have several entries from the same day, I only want to see the results once, not all the entries from the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are not doing any aggregation, so remove `group by`
2. You can replace the operator `IN` with `=` because you are comparing against 1 value only
3. Use the function `DATE()` to get only the date part from `created_at`

---

You need a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause to get the row with the minimum `id` (since it does not matter whic row will be returned) of each day:

```
SELECT g.id, g.ean, g.avg_price, DATE_FORMAT(g.created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') created_at
FROM graph g
WHERE g.ean = '00000000166330'
AND g.id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM graph WHERE ean = g.ean AND DATE(created_at) = DATE(g.created_at))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ec571f1950f5f3c2e8083a8aee10c137).

Comment: But if I have several entires from the same day, I see both, that's why I use group by

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=36183c2af81a2934db8bc1875dfc9b44

Comment: I asked for sample data and expected results in my comment under your question and you posted a link to a fiddle. Why did you post sample data not representative of your actual data?

Comment: And if you want only 1 row which row of the rows do you want?

Comment: It does not matter as long as there is only one per day.

Comment: It works to show: -Only one result/day. -Only the date and not the hour.

But, how I change the format the date is displayed?

Comment: How do you want 2020-06-11 displayed?

Comment: With format day, month, year, not year, month, day.

Answer (score 2):

If you want distinct values without aggregation function you should use DISTINCT and for date you can use the `date_format()` function

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(created_at)
 , date_format(date(created_at),'%d, %m, %Y') , id, avg_price 
FROM graph WHERE ean = '00000000166330';
```

and when you have only a value you should use `=`  and not `IN` operator.

Comment: With this query I get almost what I wanted:


SELECT DISTINCT DAY(created_at), date(created_at) , id, avg_price 
FROM graph WHERE ean = '00000000166330' group by DAY(created_at);


                   But the format of the date is still: year, month, day.
Can I change it to %d, %m, %Y ?